# SPA Architecture questions

Tags: security, memory-management, knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

This post is intended to start a deeper discussion on Single Page Applications for the web. There are questions that do not seem to have a clear answer in most resources on the subject.
They are in my mind

1. Authorization and authentication.
   With entire web app being on the client, it may make calls to the server in any of its functions, even those that the user does not have rights to.  The fact that the user cannot see a menu, does not preclude that person from invoking java script functions.  This is easily handled in MVC app, for example, by using controllers that validate user rights to a specific function based on a cookie for example.  However, some SPA apps just use single controller with Breeze or Web Api, which make authorization server side impossible.
2. Memory management on the client
   For small sample apps this is not an issue, but imagine an app with 100's of screens or an app with a single screen that pulls thousands of records over the course of one day.  With persistent caching one could imagine large memory issues, especially on under-powered devices with little RAM, like phones or tablets.  How can a group of developers had SPA route without a clear vision of handling memory management?
3. Three Tier deployment
   Some IT departments will never allow applications with a connection string to a database located on front end web servers.  Every SPA demo I have seen is structured exactly like that, including Breeze or Web Api for that matter.
4. Unobtrusive validation.
   It would require developers to use MVC partial views and controllers instead of just HTML files, which seems to fly in the face of SPA concepts, while it provides a very robust way to easily incorporate validation and UI to support it into web applications.
5. Exposing primary integer based keys in the url.
   This is non-no  in OWASP.
   As a result, SPA applications "seem" to target areas with few security requirements and small feature sets.  What do you think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

@Sergey - I think this is just too broad a question for StackOverflow. S.O. isn't a discussion forum; it's a place to go for specific answers. So while your questions are potentially valid, I don't think you should hold out much hope for deep substantive responses here.

May I add, in the friendliest possible way, that your sweeping, unsupported, and negative statements make you look like a troll. You're not a troll are you Sergey?

On the chance that you are in fact authentically concerned, I offer a few quick reactions, particularly as they pertain to Breeze.

1. **Authorization**. In Web API you can authorize at the method level. The ApiController base class has a `User` property that returns the `IPrincipal`. So whether you have one controller or many (and you can have many in Breeze if you want), the granularity is method level, not just class level.
2. **Memory management**. Desktop developers have coped with this concern for years. It may cause you some astonishment if you've always developed traditional web apps where process lifetimes are brief.  But long-running processes are not news to those of us who built large apps in desktop technologies such as WinForms, WPF, and Silverlight. The issues and solutions are much the same in the land of HTML and JavaScript.
3. **Layers on the backend**. You've been looking at demos too long. Yes most demos dump everything into one project running on one server. We assume you know how to refactor the server to meet scaling, performance and security requirements for your environment. Our demos are concerned mostly with front-end SPA development. We do dabble at the service boundary to show how data flow through a service API, through an ORM, through to the database. We thought it sufficient to identify these distinct layers and leave as an exercise for the reader the comparatively trivial matter of moving these layers to different tiers. We may have to re-visit that assumption someday. But does anyone seriously believe that there are significant obstacles to distributing layers/responsibilities across server-side tiers? Really? Like what?
4. **Unobtrusive validation**. When most people start using the word "unobtrusive" in connection with HTML, they are usually making a point about keeping JavaScript out the HTML. Perhaps that's what you mean too, in which case SPA developers everywhere agree ... and that's why there are numerous "unobtrusive validation" libraries available. HTML 5 validation, jQuery validation and Knockout validation come to mind. All of them are in the SPA developer's toolkit and none of them "require developers to use MVC partial views and controllers". What gives you the impression that a SPA would need *any server-side resources of any kind* to implement validation with JavaScript-free HTML markup?
5. **Ids as security risk**. Really? This is bogus. The key value is no more a security risk than any other data value. Millions of applications - not just SPAs - communicate key values to the client, both in the URL and in the body. It's standard in REST APIs. It's standard in ODATA. And you want to dismiss them all by saying that they "*target areas with few security requirements and small feature sets*"? Good luck with that. I think you'll have to do better than rest your case on a link to a relatively obscure organization's entire web site.

Comment: Agreed on all points. I'll add that auth is done on the server and there are many examples of auth with ASP.NET to refer to. RE: connection strings .. simply move it to another layer if that concerns you. RE: validation ... always validate on the server, but add to the client for a better user experience. How you design it is up to you, though I also like separation. If you dont like IDs in the URL's, then don't use them.

Comment: I apologize if I can across negatively.

Comment: I apologize if I can across negatively.
Thank you both very much!
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I have built some SPA applications, ranging from small to large (over 100 scripts and views). Only a handful of them had every view accessible to the public. The rest went through a strict access structure. It was so simple to return a 401 unauthorized from the server and the client just handling the 401 to redirect it to the login screen. Mr. Ward and Mr. Papa put it right. Get out of the Demo mode and try to find solutions to the issues you come across. I have watched John Papa's SPA on pluralsight, gone through numerous articles and applications on Breeze and I have to tell you, none of my applications use Breeze to do queries from the client side, because YOU DON'T NEED TO!!

Moreover, I have only extended what I have learnt and come up with my own way of solving problems. This is not an answer to your queries, but I only can provide a short comment. No technique is perfect and there is no ONE way to do everything. My server side is locked down where it needs to be locked down, my routes on the client side are locked down (if using durandal take a look at guardRoute), my scripts are minified and my images are sprited (if there is a word like that). All in all, SPA is a great technique, you got to find solutions to the quirks!

Comment: Thanks, Sujesh.  Appreciate your feedback